# How to split array into rows in Postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, split

When running this query:

```
  SELECT id,selected_placements
  FROM  app_data.content_cards
```

I get a table like this:

```
+----+-------------------------------+
| id | selected_placements           |
+----+-------------------------------+
| 90 | {162,108,156,80,163,155,NULL} |
+----+-------------------------------+
| 91 | {}                            |
+----+-------------------------------+
```

What I want to do now is get this same information but with the arrays splitted into rows so I get a result like this:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | selected_placements |
+----+---------------------+
| 90 | 162                 |
+----+---------------------+
| 90 | 108                 |
+----+---------------------+
| 90 | 156                 |
+----+---------------------+
| 90 | 80                  |
+----+---------------------+
| 90 | 163                 |
+----+---------------------+
| 90 | 155                 |
+----+---------------------+
```

As you can see I don't want to get rows with null value in "selected_placements".

I am using PostgreSQL 8.0.2.

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm confused.  I thought Redshift didn't support arrays: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-datatypes.html.

Comment: You are right @GordonLinoff in this case it is only PostgreSQL 8.0.2 what I am using. Just edited that out.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would suggest that you upgrade your version of Postgres.  All supported versions support `unnest()`:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT id, UNNEST(selected_placements) as selected_placement
      FROM  app_data.content_cards
     ) x
WHERE selected_placement IS NOT NULL;
```

In earlier versions, you can strive to pick them out one at a time.  The following is tested and works, albeit in 9.5:

```
with content_cards as (
     select 1 as id, array['a', 'b', 'c'] as selected_placements
    )
SELECT id, selected_placements[num] as selected_placement
FROM (SELECT cc.*, generate_series(1, ccup.maxup) as num
      FROM content_cards cc CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT MAX(ARRAY_UPPER(cc.selected_placements, 1)) as maxup
            FROM content_cards cc
           ) ccup
     ) x
WHERE selected_placements[num]  IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer. I get this error when running the query https://screencast.com/t/uBL3cGwt To give you some background, when I check the database version we use, this is what I get: version PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.1232. From what I understand, I am reading all the data from Redshift (using SQLWorkbenchJ), but actually it is coming from a Postgresql db that we have separately. The synchronization between the two dbs is done with stitchdata.com. Thank you very much!

Comment: I already checked in a separate environment where I have PostgreSQL 9.4.7. and the unnest () answer works perfect. I am upvoting the answer already but it would be great if I could get a solution for the other error I am having. Thank you!