# how to split rows into multiple rows based on values in an array column in postgresql? (see example in description)

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

i a have postgresql query that gets results like this:

```
id | arrayElements
 0 | [0, 2, 1]
 1 | [0, 3]
 2 | [1]
```

In the above example the values inside `arrayElements` means something. I want to split this table based on those arrayElements (to get count).

I want to convert it to:

```
id | arrayElement
 0 | 0
 0 | 2
 0 | 1
 1 | 0
 1 | 3
 2 | 1
```

here i'm essentially spliting rows by elements inside `arrayElements` column. `arrayElements` column contains string data.

i am using postgresql 14.

my end goal is to get the count per arrayElement which is why i'm separating them into different rows.

how should I solve this?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43573001/how-to-split-array-into-rows-in-postgresql) not helpful?

Comment: What data type is `arrayelements`? You state it's an array, but the data looks more like a JSON value.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, UNNEST(string_to_array(arrayElements, ',') as arrayElement;
```

should do it. In my case `arrayElement` was a string that I had to convert to an array.

There may be the case that elements might have a '[' or ']' at the beginning or end so to fix that you can modify the query to use SUBSTRING and remove those square brackets:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(UNNEST(string_to_array(arrayElements, ',')), '([0-9]{1,10})') AS "arrayElement",
  COUNT(id)
FROM table
GROUP BY arrayElement
```

the regex used in substring assumes that the maximum number of digits arrayElement can have is 10.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to get count of `arrayElements`, you can do this:

```
select sum(cardinality(arrayElements)) from tableName;
```

Comment: He said he wants to get count and my answer was that he can do it without unnesting the array.